Google Sheets 2 cells with identical functions, one is true, one is false; why?
Normal Behavior
I am creating a spreadsheet to track character builds in D&D 5e. I am trying to have the cells below "Barbarian Unarmored Defense" and "Monk Unarmored Defense" check for values in the lower ranges, then return a blank if they are filled or levels in their corresponding class are not taken. The Monk one works fine with the formula designed, seen here;


The exact same formula in the next cell returns differently


Markdown Table



A1 Scores
B1 Strength
C1 Dexterity
D1 Constitution
E1 Intelligence
F1 Wisdom
G1 Charisma
H1
I1 Core
J1 Level
K1 Proficiency
L1 Per Rest Class Resources
M1
N1
O1
P1




A2 Base
8
10
10
10
16
10


10
4
Artificer Prepared Spells
Barbarian Rage
Rage Damage
Bardic Inspiration
Song of Rest


A3 Adjust








Spell Slots
Pact Slots

3
+2




A4 Mod Adjust










Blood Curses & Hemocraft Die
Cleric Prepared Spells
Channel Divinity<br>(Cleric/Paladin)
Druid Prepared Spells
Wild Shapes (Druid)


A5 Mod
-1
=IF((SIGN(ROUNDDOWN((C2-10+C3)/2+C4))<0), ROUNDDOWN((C2-10+C3)/2+C4), "+" & ROUNDDOWN((C2-10+C3)/2+C4))
+0
+0
=IF((SIGN(ROUNDDOWN((F2-10+F3)/2+F4))<0), ROUNDDOWN((F2-10+F3)/2+F4), "+" & ROUNDDOWN((F2-10+F3)/2+F4))
+0











A6 Save
-1
+0
+0
+0
+3
+0

Indomitable<br>(Fighter)
Sneak Attack<br>(Rogue)
Ki Points<br>(Monk)
Martial Arts Dice
Unarmored Movement (Monk)





A7 Proficient?









5
1d6
10ft





A8 Expert?







Paladin Prepared Spells
Favored Foe<br>(Ranger)
Nature's Veil<br>(Ranger)
Sorcery Points
Arcane Recovery





A9

















A10 Stats
Current HP
Max HP
AC

Class Levels
Artificer
Barbarian
Arcane Trickster Levels
Eldritch Knight Levels

Eldritch Invocations
Mystic Arcanum 6th
Mystic Arcanum 7th
Mystic Arcanum 8th



A11 Base

0
13



5










A12 Adjust




Bard
Blood Hunter
Cleric
Barbarian Unarmored Defense
Monk Unarmored Defense








A13 Temp Effect







=IF(OR(ISBLANK($H$15), NOT(ISBLANK(I19:M19)), NOT(ISBLANK(J16:P16))), "", 10+$F$5+$C$5)
=IF(OR(ISBLANK($H$15), NOT(ISBLANK(I19:M19)), NOT(ISBLANK(J16:P16))), "", 10+$F$5+$C$5)
13
0
0





A14




Druid
Fighter
Monk
Mage Armor
Padded/Leather Armor
Studded Leather Armor
Hide Armor
Chain Shirt
Scale Mail / Spiked Armor
Breastplate



A15 Level
Rolled HP
Level




5










A16 1
Always Max

11

Paladin
Ranger
Rogue










A17 2


12




Ring Mail
Chain Mail
Splint
Plate
Shield
Custom
Custom



A183


13

Sorcerer
Warlock
Wizard

Requires 13 STR
Requires 15 STR
Requires 15 STR






A19 4


14














A20 5


15














A216


16

Subclass Select












A22 7


17

Artificer
Barbarian
Bard
Blood Hunter
Cleric
Druid
Fighter
Monk
Paladin
Ranger



A23 8


18














A24 9


19














A25 10


20














A26


















Troubleshooting & Spreadsheet Link
The exact same formula works in the cell next to it, with all the same cell addresses and everything... so
I expected them to output the same value. Steps I have taken to troubleshoot, reverting each after attempt;

Changes to the ranges or cell IDs at all continues to return an empty cell If I change the true condition--that is always output, regardless of whether the other cells are filled or blank

Changes to the false condition are never output, regardless of whether the other cells are filled or blank

Emptying or filling H15 does not affect the output of I13's function



You need to array-enable your current formula as such:
=arrayformula(IF(OR(ISBLANK($H$15), NOT(ISBLANK(I19:M19)), NOT(ISBLANK(J16:P16))), "", 10+$F$5+$C$5))


the reason being a simple NOT(ISBLANK(J16:P16)) does not
automatically apply to the whole range of J16:P16; if you are
applying this formula in Column J(any possible row) it picks only J16
as the target cell. if applied in Column_L then target cell is L16
and so on...
Since Barbarian Unarmored Defenseis outside the zone (as highlighted
in the screenshot) it evalutes to TRUE and the output results to blank



